# How to set the programming language in eclipse's editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

I am using **Eclipse Luna**, and I opened a java file *with no extension*. Eclipse editor treats it as normal text, how do I set the programming language in the editor without editing file extension or doing any external operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the file name. Then do

Open With -> Other... -> Java Editor

Comment: I do not have *Java Editor* as my option. And that requires renaming the file, because on Windows 7 I can't do *Open With* for files with not extensions. Is there a way to do it from eclipse?

Comment: The steps above are from within Eclipse. Do you have the file imported into Eclipse already?

Comment: No, the file is external, not in eclipse.

Comment: To open it, I simply used **File > Open File...** but it opens it as plain text, is there any way to change the programming language from there, or somehow "Open it as" a specific language file?

Comment: Hmmm... You say that the file is open as plain text. Is it open in Eclipse? If so, you can still right-click anywhere in the text area and do the "Open With" steps above. If it's not opening in Eclipse, how are you opening it? I'm a little confused.

Comment: I'm not seeing an actual answer to this question.  Am I missing something?